# How to access LAN shares with OpenVPN on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, openvpn

I feel like I'm missing something because I've been using my OpenVPN for many years now with Debian, Fedora and Macintosh clients. Never had any issues to access shares in my home LAN where my openvpn server is.

I can access SMB, AFP and NFS without problems.

But lately I've been using my OpenVPN on a Windows 7 client and I am unable to access any shares.

For example my Synology NAS at address nas.mylan.local has those three shares that I listed and I can login to its web interface, resolve it using both nas and nas.mylan.local from the Windows client but I can't access the shares.

I've tried for example \nas\Downloads, \nas.mylan.local\Downloads and trying to discover it using Network and sharing center.

If I specify direct path I get a login prompt, the Windows client I've done this one has been AD connected to another company so I type in \Username to negate the domain.

The password works in the web GUI but in the sharing prompt I get an error saying something along the lines of "User not allowed access from this computer".

The Tap device that OpenVPN uses is in Public scope, so I've gone into the Windows firewall and tried to add my LAN addresses, and my VPN address, to the allowed public IPs list of the SMB in rule for the public scope.

But no dice. Also I later noticed the Windows firewall was disabled after all.

I've also tried going into the scope sharing options and setting allow on incoming sharing requests on the Public scope.

What is up with Windows 7 and sharing over OpenVPN? I assume it's a security feature from Microsoft that is preventing me from accessing my shares since all other clients work fine.

This is the openvpn server config I've been using a couple of years now, before that it was slightly different on a Debian server.

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth minserver_static.key 1

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
persist-key
persist-tun

user openvpn
group openvpn

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN domain.local"

ca ca.crt
cert minserver.crt
key minserver.key
dh dh2048.pem

#status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
#log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
#verb 3
```

Here is the Windows 7 client config in question. It's exactly like my linux, mac and android configs. I have bash scripts and templates that generate the configs but I've omitted the certs and keys here.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote minserver 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
resolv-retry infinite
comp-lzo

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN domain.local"

# Comment this for the ovpn config
;tls-auth minserver_static.key 0
;ca ca.crt
;cert .crt
;key .key

<ca>
...
</ca>
...
```

My iptables setup on the server is very simple, just these rules.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=openvpn
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=tun0
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s  10.8.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

I doubt this is an openvpn server issue, it's most likely something in Windows.

Comment: I think that an issue is with name resolution. Try to access share by IP address instead of by name, so instead of `\\nas.mylan.local\Downloads` try `\\ip.ip.ip.ip\Downloads`

Comment: @Alex I'll try when I get back to the client but that would make it very Windows specific because I did mention that name resolution through ping and web browser is working fine.

Comment: I guess it because you using `tun` which acting as a router so don't bypass broadcast traffic that SMB likes a lot. You can try to switch to `tap`, since it layer 2(ethernet) level that acting like a switch and would bypass SMB/CIFS brodcasts  but it will spam VPN tunnel with broadcasts. If you have decent bandwidth between sites it isn't issue though